# O que acontece quando rodamos scripts PHP com tarefas longas?

Tags: php, desempenho

Estou executando um script `PHP` que é responsável por fazer download de 55'000 imagens em um servidor e fazer download destes arquivos para dentro de uma pasta em outro servidor. Deve demorar segundo estatísticas por minuto cerca de ***1h40*** para completar a tarefa.

Parece que o script vai perdendo performance conforme o tempo de execução vai passando. As perguntas são:

- O script perde performance em relação ao servidor conforme passa o tempo?
- Porque mesmo fechando a guia, o script continua rodando?
- Posso de alguma forma abortar a execução do script e relançá-lo?

Eu sei que o script está sendo executado pois ao acessar a ***[URL](http://imo.axitech.com.br/wp-content/uploads/Vista/)*** e dar F5 o contador de arquivos no diretório é modificado.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> O script perde performance em relação ao servidor conforme passa o tempo?

Depende do código. A maioria dos programadores que conheço acha que o Garbage Collector resolve qualquer problema com relação a memória e acabam provocando vazamentos (isso independe da plataforma, e é tão relevante no PHP quanto em qualquer outra).

> Porque mesmo fechando a guia, o script continua rodando?

PHP é uma tecnologia server side. O cliente (quase sempre um navegador) faz requisições, e o servidor (Apache/Tomcat/IIS) processa e dá uma resposta. A resposta será elaborada e enviada para o endereço e porta do cliente mesmo que o programa cliente seja fechado.

> Posso de alguma forma abortar a execução do script e relançá-lo?

Pode. O ideal, no entanto, é executar a tarefa longa em partes. Por exemplo, tratar cinquenta e cinco mil imagens é um tanto pesado, mas você pode tratar de vinte em vinte (ou talvez até menos) e mandar uma resposta a cada pacote de imagens para o cliente. Assim você:

- Garante que, em caso de erro, pode recomeçar a tarefa do pacote no qual parou;
- Transforma a certeza de um timeout em uma mera possibilidade, que pode ser evitada se as respostas forem constantes;

E o mais importante:

- Você pode assim limpar toda a memória consumida pelo processo a cada pacote, o que torna ainda mais fácil a tarefa de construir um sistema escalável.

Answer (score 0):

O script em si não perde perfomance porque ele não é mutável depois de interpretado pelo apache (seja qual outro servidor php) e compilado, então o código será o mesmo, o que faz perder a perfomance do mesmo é a forma que você construiu esse script e principalmente a maquina do seu servidor.

Caso você esteja utilizando um laço **for** oriento para que mude para **foreach** pois o mesmo a cada interação destroi a thread da memoria e não sobrecarrega totalmente o servidor, já o for não, ele mantem a alocação da mesma até que o laço se complete.